# Does a symbol for "married" exist in some package or font?

Tags: symbols

I would like to write something like `Bride-name \rings{} groom-name` in my text and wonder, if a symbol for rings already exist. Maybe somewhere around the symbols for "born" or "deceased" or other formal symbols such a two-rings symbol exist.

I am looking for two rings, horizontally aligned and intersecting each other. I guess, a knot-like behaviour as seen [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-olympic-rings/) would be nice, in order to distinguish it from `\infty` or similar.

Here is some code to play around with. I tried using the Olympic rings, but failed. But I guess, someone knows a symbol which is already written.

```
\documentclass[twoside=true, paper=A5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{%
    ,Ligatures={TeX}
}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{Front}{rgb}{0.85,0.8627,0.839}
\definecolor{Schrift}{rgb}{0.31,0.31,0.34}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{Schrift}}

\title{Bride-name \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path[draw=white,line width=.08cm,
     fill=Schrift,even odd rule]
     (1, 0) circle (0.18cm)
     (1, 0) circle (0.05cm);
     \path[draw=white,line width=.08cm,
     fill=Schrift,even odd rule]
     (1.2, 0) circle (0.18cm)
     (1.2, 0) circle (0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture} Groom-name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{Front}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26ad/fontsupport.htm

Comment: One would assume [`fa-link` from `fontawesome`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/link/) might be both a good OR bad choice for marriage.

Comment: I don't know whether this works with lualatex/xetex, but try `\textmarried` from `textcomp` package...

Comment: Of course, there are marriages without a bride or without a groom nowadays...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a tikz implementation which draws two interlocked rings. I defined a macro `\married` to simplify its insertion at the appropiate place.

```
% Used the same colors you defined in your example
\definecolor{ring color}{rgb}{0.31,0.31,0.34}
\definecolor{border color}{rgb}{0.85,0.8627,0.839}

\newcommand{\married}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex, y=1ex, scale=0.5, baseline=-.6ex]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,-.2) rectangle ++(5.5,2.2);
\path[draw=border color,line width=.08ex,
     fill=ring color,even odd rule]
     (0, 0) circle (2ex)
     (0, 0) ellipse (1.5ex and 1.3ex);
\path[draw=border color,line width=.08ex,
     fill=ring color,even odd rule]
     (1.5, 0) circle (2ex)
     (1.5, 0) ellipse (1.5ex and 1.3ex);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle ++(5.5,2.2);
\path[draw=border color,line width=.08ex,
     fill=ring color,even odd rule]
     (1.5, 0) circle (2ex)
     (1.5, 0) ellipse (1.5ex and 1.3ex);
\path[draw=border color,line width=.08ex,
     fill=ring color,even odd rule]
     (0, 0) circle (2ex)
     (0, 0) ellipse (1.5ex and 1.3ex);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Used as in:

```
\title{Bride-name \married{} Groom-name}
```

When inserted in your document, which uses special fonts and background color, it results in:

[image: Result]

You can play with the `scale` option to increase or reduce the size, and with the `baseline` option to adjust the vertical alignment. Of course you can change colors too:

```
\colorlet{ring color}{orange!50!yellow!80!black}
\colorlet{border color}{Front!70!white}
```

[image: Other colors]

Comment: You should eventually mention which packages are required.

Comment: @moose For the `\married` macro only `tikz` package is required. To get the result shown in the screenshots, I used the same setup than in the example provided by the OP.